# View hidden part of scrollviewer in Windows Phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7.1, crop

I'm creating a WP7 application to crop photo, then add some effects and upload to server. I want when users choose which area of photo will be cropped, they can see the remain part.

I have my photo contained in a scrollviewer, so users can scroll to position they want, and crop the visible part of photo.

However, when scrolling in scrollviewer, the hidden part of photo is totally transparent, it make users hard to figure. I want users can view invisible part with opacity about 50%.

This image can explain more clear:
[image]

Is there a workaround or another control to solve this problem?

Thank you !

Comment: Crop area size is only one of 3 modes: 480x480 (square), 480x800 (portrait) and 800x480 (landscape). Users have to choose crop mode before cropping actually, so consider crop size is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using cropping I'd try layering something over the top to create the semi-transparency.

Cropping means don't show this part of the image. It isn't just temporarily hiding it.

Comment: I need to crop photo, then add some effects and upload to server. I want when users choose which area of photo will be cropped, they can see the remain part.

Comment: I menat cropping what's displayed on the page. Without seeing your code it's hard to know what you mean and are actually doing. Is using this free tool not an acceptable alernative? http://blog.aviary.com/introducing-aviary-for-windows-phone-7/ Why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: My problem isn't how to crop, or what is cropping. I can crop and upload perfectly. It's only how can I show users when THEY ARE CHOOSING AREA TO CROP (not actually cropped yet) that the light area is cropped photo and dark area is removed part. Without scrollviewer, I cannot scroll image. But with scrollviewer, only "light area" shown, how to show the "dark area"?